How can I change other field dynamically without changing the password?
I've created an update function, but the problem I'm encountering right now is since I'm previewing the data from database through tanstack-query, the password is also set as a defaultValue therefore it shows on the UI, therefore when I submit the form, it automatically submitted the hashed password to the backend.
const EditUser = () => {

  const role = useCurrentRole()
  const { id } = useParams()
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()


  const [forcePassword, setForcePassword] = useState(true)


  const credentialForm = useForm<CreateRoleAccountSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(CreateRoleAccountSchema)
  })


  //Fetch the credentials data, user itself
  const getUserCredentials = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['userCredentials', id],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/user-credentials/getUserCredentials/${id}`)
      if (!response.data) {
        throw new Error('No user credentials found')
      }
      return response.data
    }
  })



  const updateCredential = useMutation({
    mutationKey: ['updateCredentials', id],
    mutationFn: async (values: CreateRoleAccountSchemaType) => {
      const res = await fetch(`/api/user-credentials/updateUserCredentials/${id}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(values)
      })

      if (!res.ok) {
        const errorText = await res.text();
        console.error("Server response error:", errorText);
        throw new Error("Failed to update account");
      }
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      toast({
        title: "Failed to update credentials"
      })
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ['userCredentials', id]
      });
      toast({
        title: "User credential has been updated!"
      })
    }
  })


  const handleSubmitCredential = useCallback((value: CreateRoleAccountSchemaType) => {
    updateCredential.mutate(value); // This will trigger the mutation to update credentials
  }, [updateCredential]
  )



  useEffect(() => {
    if (getUserCredentials.data) {
      credentialForm.reset({
        name: getUserCredentials.data.name,
        email: getUserCredentials.data.email,
        role: getUserCredentials.data.role,
        affiliation: getUserCredentials.data.affiliation
      })
    }
  }, [getUserCredentials.data, credentialForm.reset])
return (
<Form {...credentialForm}>
  <form >
    //Other forms
           <FormField
              control={credentialForm.control}
              name="password"
              defaultValue={getUserCredentials.data?.password}
              render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>Password*</FormLabel>
                         <FormControl>
                            <Input disabled={forcePassword} type='text' placeholder="password" {...field} />
                         </FormControl>
                  </FormItem>
                   )}
                 />

   </form>
</Form>
)
}

This is the UI, it shows the field, and for example I want to submit the data, it will also apply to the password since the defaultValue for password is set.
getUserCredentials.ts
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import bcrypt  from 'bcryptjs'

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, { params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
    try {
        const userCredential = await db.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                id: params.id
            }
        })
        if (!userCredential) {
            return NextResponse.json({ error: "User not found" }, { status: 400 })
        }

        return NextResponse.json(userCredential)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return NextResponse.json({ error: "Server Error" }, { status: 500 })
    }
}

updateUserCredentials.ts
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import bcrypt  from 'bcryptjs'
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function PATCH(req: NextRequest, { params }: { params: { id: string } }){
    
    try {
        const body = await req.json()
        const {
            name,
            email,
            password,
            role,
            affiliation
        } = body


        const existingUser = await db.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                id: params.id
            }
        })

        if(!existingUser){
            return NextResponse.json({message: "User is not authenticated"}, {status: 404})
        }

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)

        const user = await db.user.update({
            where: {
                id: params.id
            },
            data: {
                name,
                email,
                password: hashedPassword,
                role,
                affiliation
            }
        })
       
        revalidatePath('/')
        return NextResponse.json(user, {status: 200})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return NextResponse.json(error, {status: 500})
    }
}


What I'm trying to do:
I want the update to be dynamic, for example, I just want to change the email, therefore all data will be still the same  but only change the email.
What is happening
Since I'm submitting the form, all of the fields are getting submitted, for the password, since I set a defaultValue for password, it automatically update.

Why are you sending the password to the front-end? Leave it blank, and only update if there was a new input into it.
